# How can I bump a branch ahead of master?

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project that is large and long term. In the middle of development, I decided to dial back some of the features and roll out an MVP. I created a new branch from master and deleted all of the future features.

```
=====> master
     +==========> deleted-and-changed-mvp
```

I then deployed. However, `master` should be my origin branch. I forked `master` to a new branch and merged the MVP into master.

```
=====> master                            
     +==========> deleted-and-changed-mvp
     +> original-master
```

Now, I want to stack the new features on top of master but can't because its considered 20-something commits behind. How can I move this branch on top of master?

```
================> master                            
     +> original-master
```

I would prefer `original-master` to be considered ahead in the deleted files and behind in the modified/added files.

Comment: Merge deleted-and-changed-mvp into master?

Comment: So already did that. The issue is that now original-master is considered behind and the files I deleted are going to be considered lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(note : I'm not sure I understood what you wish to achieve)

You can easily "squash rebase" `original-master` as a single commit on top of `master` :

```
# from original-master :
git reset --soft master
git commit
```

With these commands, you would now have a commit :

- with the exact content of `original-master`
- on top of `master`

You can now select whatever content you want from `master` :

```
git checkout master -- fileA fileB dir1 dir2 ...
# or if you bluntly want "all the files that exist on master" :
git checkout master -- .
```

Once you are satisfied with the content :

```
git commit
# or
git commit --amend
```

Comment: I documented what I did but I am going to mark your answer as correct for any others that have this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up simply merging with master and then reverting the invididual commits to undo the file deletions.